# Using hover and click with jQuery UI tabs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, hover, jquery-ui-tabs

I am using the following code for my jQuery UI tabs:

```
$('#tabs').tabs({
    fx: { opacity: 'toggle', duration: 400 }}).tabs('rotate', 1000);
$("#tabs").hover(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs("rotate",0);
},

function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs("rotate",1000);
});

$("#tabs").click(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs('rotate', 0);
});
```

The tabs are rotating properly and the rotation stop when hovering with the mouse. However, the 'hover' function is also overriding the 'click' function. How can I achieve a pause when hovering, and a complete stop to the rotation on click?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('#tabs').tabs({ 
    fx: { opacity: 'toggle', duration: 400 }
}).tabs('rotate', 1000);

$("#tabs").hover(
    function() {
        $("#tabs").stop();
    },
    function() {
        $("#tabs").tabs("rotate",1000);
    }
);

$("#tabs").click(
    function() {
        $("#tabs").stop(true);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

just a week ago i looked for the same issue. Now i created an [extesion: Pause on Hover for jQuery UI Tabs Rotate](https://github.com/tigusigalpa/jQuery-UI-tabs-Rotate-Pause-on-hover)